# Code flow doesn't reach the render function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

ly In the following code, the render function is called in the loop below. The wierd thing is that the line of code before the function call(console.log) works but the console.log directy inside the function doesn't work. check out the for(var i in coupons) line
Moreover, the line after the function call doesn't work.console,log(e). Also d is only executed once instead of 3 times as the length of the array is 3
I am unable to use the popup's console because it crashes my system(yes it actually does). So I am having to rely on this.

```
function render(template,object){
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("Hello")//This doesn't
    var placeholders=/\$\{([A-Za-a0-9_]+)\}/.exec(template);
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(placeholders);//Neither does this

}
function update(){
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'fetchCoupons'},
                function(couponsObj) {
                    // chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('coupons');
                     //chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log($.tmpl);
                     var template=$("#coupons-template").html()
                   //$(".coupons").html(template    )
                   //$couponscontent=$.tmpl(template,coupons)
                    var coupons=couponsObj.coupons;
                    var deals=couponsObj.deals;
                         chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log(coupons);

                    for(i in coupons){
                        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("d");//This console.log works
                        render(template,coupouns[i]);//This line calls the render function
                        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log("e");

                    }
                }
        );

}

        update();
```

Comment: lots of unexplained "doesn't work"s.there. care to expand?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo which is causing the code to halt at the call to `render`:

```
render(template,coupouns[i]);
```

Should be:

```
render(template,coupons[i]);
```

coupouns -> coupons